# Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, sql-server

This warning can happen for many different reasons, however, I think that my problem here is that the table `APPT` is empty/and doesn't contain any `row` with the `t_schedule_id`.  I read every question that may already have my answer, and all answers stated the same thing "your SQL query is not being successful and a FALSE boolean value is being returneds "..So yes, I know that the query is returning false because there is 0 rows with the `t_schedule_id`  and that is my point, I want my function to return the `int` `0` when there is `0` row with `t_schedule_id`

function.php

```
function get_appt($schedule_id,$conn){

    $query = "select t_schedule_id as t_schedule_id from [dbo].[APPT] where t_schedule_id = .$schedule_id.; ";

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);

    if ($row_count === false){
       return 0;
    }else{
       return $row_count;
    }
 }
```

application.php

```
$get_appt = get_appt(1, $conn);
echo $get_appt;
```

So, my question is how can I stop getting this `warning`, no matter if the table return `0` If is `0` is `0` if is a `number > 0` then return that number.

PS: I know there is no error in my query name such as `table name, column name etc ...`  And, when I `echo $get_appt;` I get the value `0` but also the warning

> Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 220

And this is line 220 `$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);`

Comment: why not query for `count(t_schedule_id)` instead?

Comment: I will have this warning `warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Comment: A quick look reveals a blatant syntax error in your SQL code. None of those answers you claimed you've read explain how to fetch the error message?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález nop most of them just claim that `the query` might be wrong; typo, names, etc

Comment: Please check [sqlsrv_errors()](http://php.net/sqlsrv_errors).

Comment: Your query isn't returning what you expect because of a syntax error - that is, it's not even executing. Looks like you need to remove the dots around $schedule_id in your query.

Comment: @fridge_light yessssssssssssss....you got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is failing to execute due to a syntax error in the query string. Consequently, `sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt)` throws an error. Remove the dots around $schedule_id so that $query becomes:

```
$query = "select t_schedule_id as t_schedule_id from [dbo].[APPT] where t_schedule_id = $schedule_id";
```

Checking for errors with sqlsrv_errors() will help to debug future issues. This returns an array and can be output using `print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true);` - see 
http://php.net/sqlsrv_errors.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
function get_appt($schedule_id,$conn){

    $query = "select t_schedule_id as t_schedule_id from [dbo].[APPT] where t_schedule_id = .$schedule_id.; ";

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

    if ($stmt === false){
       return 0;
    }else{
       return sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't remove the syntax error or check for error messages. How does it solve the question?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - I supposed that the syntax was valid, maybe some sqlserver specific. If the syntax is wrong fridge_light is right.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax I think is like this:

`$query = "select t_schedule_id as t_schedule_id from [dbo].[APPT] where t_schedule_id =" .$schedule_id."; ";`

You missed 2 `"` charaters