# PHP Check if MS SQL Database exist?

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I want to check if the database 'example' exist in my ms sql server 
The code doesnt seem to work :/ 
Im getting, 
**sqlsrv_num_rows expects parameter 1 to be in resource**

## config.php

```
<?php
$userID=$_SESSION['userID']; 
$serverName = ''; 
$uid = '';   
$pwd = '';   
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                         "Database"=>$userID); 

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


?>
```

## file.php

```
<?php

function checkForUserDB($userID){

    $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
    include('config.php');
    $sql="SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME ='".$userID."'";
    $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
    $count=sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1){

        echo "Database Exist!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Database does not exist!";

    }
}



checkForUserDB('example');

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: sqlsrv\_num\_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343796/warning-sqlsrv-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems:

- First, you are not checking the return value of `sqlsrv_query()`, which returns `FALSE` if the query fails, and in that case you're passing `FALSE` to `sqlsrv_num_rows()`, which seems to be your first problem. You have to do something like this:

  ```
  $result=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
  if ($result===false) {
    // only print SQL error while debugging, in production log the error to a file
    exit("Error executing query: ".sqlsrv_errors());
  }
  else {
    $count=sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
    // rest of your code
  }
  ```
- Then, you are using the wrong field of [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/schemata-transact-sql), in SQL Server the database is `CATALOG` but you are checking `SCHEMA_NAME` which is, well, the schema, being the default schema of SQL Server `dbo`.
- Finally, you are trying to check if a database exists *trying to connect in first place to that database*, so if the database doesn't exists the connection fails, and since you aren't checking the result of `sqlsrv_connect()` this is probably the cause of the failed `sqlsrv_query()` later. You have to connect to a database that always exists, not to the database that you want to check:

  ```
  $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                           "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                           "Database"=>'YourMainDatabase'; // this database must exists
  ```

Comment: So basically, if the connection attempt to the database fails, the database doesnt exist. If it connects it exist. Do you know the error codes which sql will return if the database doesnt exist. Becouse if there is something wrong with my connection (server errors) it would return the same error

Comment: You could do detection based on failed connection, and [there are specific error codes for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/appendix-a-odbc-error-codes), but I think it's better use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` approach, anyway if you are going to create the DB if doesn't exists you need a working connection.